# Importing a large amount of XML data into Google App Engine

Tags: python, xml, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a reasonably large amount of XML data (about 200MB) that I want to import into an App Engine datastore.

So far I've tried creating the models and using the cElementTree parser to load the entities, but it is taking a long time.

I also have concerns about how well the datastore will handle this much data, and if there is a better way.

So my questions are, what is the fastest way of parsing XML into App Engine, and is there a better backend that will handle storing several hundred thousand entities / records.

Comment: App Engine's datastore can definitely handle that much data.  What you need to consider is what indexes your data requires, because unneeded indexes will slow down writes and bloat your storage requirements.

Are you writing to the localhost's datastore (dev_appserver) or remote datastore? Because the local datastore will be very slow unless you are using the sqllite option.

Comment: That's good to know. I'm currently using the local dev server, so that'll be why it's so slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with the [Bulk Loader](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Configuring_the_Bulk_Loader) that supports reading data from an XML source.
Regarding the size of the XML, Datastore will have no problem at all to handle such amount of data.

Comment: This site has an example of using bulkloader with xml data: http://bulkloadersample.appspot.com/  (Also the video linked at the bottom is helpful)